# Internal Error when type checking the RPS example

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

Here is the [example from core.typed github page:](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed/blob/master/module-check/src/test/clojure/clojure/core/typed/test/rps_async.clj)

```
(ns typedclj.rps-async
  (:require [clojure.core.typed :as t]
            [clojure.core.async :as a]
            [clojure.core.typed.async :as ta]))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Types
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(t/defalias Move
            "A legal move in rock-paper-scissors"
            (t/U ':rock ':paper ':scissors))

(t/defalias PlayerName
            "A player's name in rock-paper-scissors"
            t/Str)

(t/defalias PlayerMove
            "A move in rock-paper-scissors. A Tuple of player name and move"
            '[PlayerName Move])

(t/defalias RPSResult
            "The result of a rock-paper-scissors match.
            A 3 place vector of the two player moves, and the winner"
            '[PlayerMove PlayerMove PlayerName])

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Implementation
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

(t/ann MOVES (t/Vec Move))
(def MOVES [:rock :paper :scissors])

(t/ann BEATS (t/Map Move Move))
(def BEATS {:rock :scissors, :paper :rock, :scissors :paper})

(t/ann rand-player [PlayerName -> (ta/Chan PlayerMove)])
(defn rand-player
  "Create a named player and return a channel to report moves."
  [name]
  (let [out (ta/chan :- PlayerMove)]
    (ta/go (while true (a/>! out [name (rand-nth MOVES)])))
    out))

(t/ann winner [PlayerMove PlayerMove -> PlayerName])
(defn winner
  "Based on two moves, return the name of the winner."
  [[name1 move1] [name2 move2]]
  (cond
    (= move1 move2) "no one"
    (= move2 (BEATS move1)) name1
    :else name2))

(t/ann judge [(ta/Chan PlayerMove) (ta/Chan PlayerMove) -> (ta/Chan RPSResult)])
(defn judge
  "Given two channels on which players report moves, create and return an
  output channel to report the results of each match as [move1 move2 winner]."
  [p1 p2]
  (let [out (ta/chan :- RPSResult)]
    (ta/go
      (while true
        (let [m1 (a/<! p1)
              m2 (a/<! p2)]
          (assert m1)
          (assert m2)
          (a/>! out (t/ann-form [m1 m2 (winner m1 m2)]
                                RPSResult)))))
    out))

(t/ann init (t/IFn [PlayerName PlayerName -> (ta/Chan RPSResult)]
                   [-> (ta/Chan RPSResult)]))
(defn init
  "Create 2 players (by default Alice and Bob) and return an output channel of match results."
  ([] (init "Alice" "Bob"))
  ([n1 n2] (judge (rand-player n1) (rand-player n2))))

(t/ann report [PlayerMove PlayerMove PlayerName -> nil])
(defn report
  "Report results of a match to the console."
  [[name1 move1] [name2 move2] winner]
  (println)
  (println name1 "throws" move1)
  (println name2 "throws" move2)
  (println winner "wins!"))

(t/ann play [(ta/Chan RPSResult) -> nil])
(defn play
  "Play by taking a match reporting channel and reporting the results of the latest match."
  [out-chan]
  (let [[move1 move2 winner] (a/<!! out-chan)]
    (assert move1)
    (assert move2)
    (assert winner)
    (report move1 move2 winner)))

(t/ann play-many [(ta/Chan RPSResult) t/Int -> (t/Map t/Any t/Any)])
(defn play-many
  "Play n matches from out-chan and report a summary of the results."
  [out-chan n]
  (t/loop [remaining :- t/Int, n
           results :- (t/Map PlayerName t/Int), {}]
          (if (zero? remaining)
            results
            (let [[m1 m2 winner] (a/<!! out-chan)]
              (assert m1)
              (assert m2)
              (assert winner)
              (recur (dec remaining)
                     (merge-with + results {winner 1}))))))


(fn []
  (t/ann-form (a/<!! (init))
              (t/U nil RPSResult)))
```

If you check it in the repl:

```
(clojure.core.typed/check-ns 'typedclj.rps-async)
```

You get an error:

```
Initializing core.typed ...
Building core.typed base environments ...
Finished building base environments
"Elapsed time: 9213.869003 msecs"
core.typed initialized.
Start collecting typedclj.rps-async
Start collecting clojure.core.typed.async
Finished collecting clojure.core.typed.async
Finished collecting typedclj.rps-async
Collected 2 namespaces in 1725.941447 msecs
Not checking clojure.core.typed (does not depend on clojure.core.typed)
Not checking clojure.core.async (does not depend on clojure.core.typed)
Not checking clojure.core.async.impl.channels (does not depend on clojure.core.typed)
Not checking clojure.core.async.impl.ioc-macros (does not depend on clojure.core.typed)
Not checking clojure.core.async.impl.protocols (does not depend on clojure.core.typed)
Not checking clojure.core.async.impl.dispatch (does not depend on clojure.core.typed)
Not checking clojure.core.typed.util-vars (does not depend on clojure.core.typed)
Start checking clojure.core.typed.async
Checked clojure.core.typed.async in 502.126883 msecs
Start checking typedclj.rps-async
Type Error (typedclj/rps_async.clj:91:13) Internal Error (typedclj/rps_async.clj:91:5) Bad call to path-type: nil, ({:idx 0})
ExceptionInfo Type Checker: Found 1 error  clojure.core/ex-info (core.clj:4403)
```

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This is a core.typed bug. Please file a ticket [here](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CTYP).